# How do I eliminate duplicate code in a rails erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, railstutorial.org

What do I do to eliminate the double code that's happening?

**In about.html.erb I have the following code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= @title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pages#about</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/pages/about.html.erb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**In the browser at localhost:3000/pages/about**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SampleApp</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="ra/NXpqBo1ccudzQ2HGHoo3OrZB2bLX732MQl+EJHU4=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pages#about</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/pages/about.html.erb</p>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use layout by default is application layout you only require only content

Comment: Hey Amar. Thanks for commenting. How would I execute the advice you gave me.

Comment: In about.html.erb keep only

"<h1>Pages#about</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/about.html.erb</p>"

Comment: I got it Amar. thank you! The duplicate is part of app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. I'm going to use that to be more dry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate is part of app/views/layouts/application.html.erb